# 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, migration

When I try to make migrations for the following models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    latitude = models.FloatField
    longitude = models.FloatField
    altitude = models.IntegerField

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name

    def getLatitude(self):
        return self.latitude

    def getLongitude(self):
        return self.longitude

class Distance(models.Model):
    placeA = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    placeB = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    placeAlatitude = placeA.getLatitude()
    placeBlatitude = placeB.getLatitude()
    placeAlongitude = Location.objects.select_related().get(placeA.longitude)
    placeBlongitude = Location.objects.select_related().get(placeB.longitude)
    distance = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)
```

I am getting the error:

> 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'getLatitude'

I get a similar error if I try to directly access the latitude directly (`placeA.latitude`)

What am I doing wrong? I am new to using the Django framework.

Comment: placeAlatitude = placeA.getLatitude() what is this means !!!

Comment: @a_k_v The distance class stores the distance between placeA and placeB. To do that I need to get the latitude and longitudes of each location. I am trying to use the getLatitude function defined in Location class to return the latitude of placeA

Comment: Unrelated, but the `getLatitude` and `getLongitude` methods are plain useless - `latitude` and `longitude` are public attributes, you don't need getters.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This is just for the initial phase. Other constraints would be added in later

Comment: @CoderBrain you still don't need them. Python has a strong support for computed attributes (`property` etc), so you can always turn a plain attribute into a computed one later. But if you really want explicit accessors, then at least do not expose the attributes as part of the class API: rename them as `_latitude` and `_longitude` (the leading underscore is the naming convention for "protected"). Since those are models fields you'll also probably want to set the fields `db_column` argument to (resp) "latitude" and "longitude" to avoid a schema migration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all there is likely an error in your `Location` model: you here do not *construct* the `FloatField`s and `IntegerField`: you only pass a reference to the class, you do not "call" it. So in order to define these columns, you should add parenthesis:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    altitude = models.IntegerField()

    # ...
```

Next you can not define `placeAlatitude`, etc. with `placeA.GetLatitude()`, at class level `placeA` is a `ForeignKey` object, *not* a `Location`, object, you can however define a `@property` here that will, for a `Distance` object, fetch the correct attribute of the related objects:

```
class Distance(models.Model):
    placeA = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    placeB = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    distance = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)

    @property
    def placeAlatitude(self):
        return self.placeA.latitude

    @property
    def placeBlatitude(self):
        return self.placeB.latitude

    @property
    def placeAlongitude(self):
        return self.placeA.longitude

    @property
    def placeBlongitude(self):
        return self.placeB.longitude
```

Comment: Looking for a solution to this problem for like a month, and i resolved trough this answer, many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but what if i want the Distance to be inpendent in the future?
For instance i witll change the latitude and altitude of the Location and i dont wont that to effect the already saved Distance object (That took the previous values)

Comment: @Bhbf: then you don't create a `ForeignKey`, and you let the view fill in the values of the existing location.

Comment: maybe i can direct you to my question to discuss it more there :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485800/how-to-get-a-model-variable-name-from-another-model-in-django

Answer (score 1):

In your model, you are defining the structure. You can't use

```
placeAlatitude = placeA.getLatitude()
placeBlatitude = placeB.getLatitude()
```

placeAlatitude and placeBlatitude must be define the type of model. You can't simply return value.

From analyzing your model these two fields are not necessary it is redundant values(same case for placeAlongitude and placeBlongitude). You defined a foreign key relation to location. So you can access longitude and latitude by using that relation.