# How to get a Model variable name from another model in django

Tags: python, django

I have two models in django model

Model.py

```
class RequestTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Author=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    defaultvalues=models.CharField(max_length=50)



class Request(models.Model):
    name = ?? # 
    Author = ??

    starttime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    endtime = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

so the idea is that i want to create `Requesttemplate` which i can use in the future to create a `Request`  object that will take the name and the Author variables from the template.

I tried to use `Forgienkey` to the `name` variable, but in case i updated the template in the future i dont want to get my Request updated.

**Conclusion**:
I want to  connect the Request with the template for one time (to get the variables names) and then keep it independent from the template.

### Any ideas?

Update

```
class RequestTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Author=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    defaultvalues=models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Request(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     starttime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     endtime = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

Views.py

```
def clone_to_request(request, pk):
    request_template = get_object_or_404(RequestTemplate, pk=pk)
    request = Request.objects.create(
        name=request_template.name,
        Author=request_template.author
    )
```

urls.py

```
from .views import clone_to_request


urlpatterns=[path('create/',clone_to_request),]
```

Comment: You can inherit your response from the template class Request(RequestTemplate)

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

Just use two simple fields:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    starttime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    endtime = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

In the view, you can then construct a `Request` based on the `RequestTemplate`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def clone_to_request(request, pk):
    request_template = get_object_or_404(RequestTemplate, pk=pk)
    request = Request.objects.create(
        name=request_template.name,
        author=request_template.author
    )
    # …
```

Here we thus create a new `Request` based on the primary key of the `RequestTemplate`.

Comment: That didnt work actually, if im updating the name or the author from the RequestTemplate that will affected the already created Request object

Comment: @Ezz: no, if you update that of the `RequestTemplate` *after* you cloned it into the `Request`, it will not have impact on the already created `Request`s. Of course on the future ones, it will.

Comment: i added the code in the original question

Comment: @Ezz: exactly how are you *using* the view? If you trigger the view it will make a clone. So if you then update the `RequestTemplate` that clone constructed *before* will still have the old values. If you of course trigger the view again, then it makes another clone with the new data.

Comment: I will explain to you more, i want the user to go the /create page and he is supposed to add new Request, this Request takes (name,Author and starttime and endtime), he should get the form with the option of choosing which Requesttemplate he wants to use. Once he choose the Requesttemplate the name and the authour will be automatically assigned to this Request and he has to enter the starttime and endtime and this Request will be saved.

Comment: I hope its more clear now

Comment: @Ezz: sure the `RequestTemplate` you pick should thus be the `pk` of the item that then makes a clone. You can thus use a form that makes a POST request and has the primary key of the `RequestTemplate` to clone.

Comment: can you explain more please